# Add a new language in android without republishing the app

Tags: android, multilingual

I know how develop a multilingual app in Android.
The following link explains how to do so.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Assume that I release to the market my app in 3 different languages developed with the best practices described in the link above in mind.

If I want to add a new language I have to republish a new version. Is there a good way to avoid republishing the app if I add more languages?

It is important that the application detects the correct language according to the language of the smartphone.

Comment: What would be wrong with re-publishing the app?  Wouldn't you want to localize the description text for your app as it appears in the app store for each new language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the **standard localization framework** then the answer is **no**, because all the localization files are looked up in the *res* folder at runtime. And to update the *res* folder, you need to update the **apk**.

The only possible way to do what you want is by coding your own localization framework, which, intuitively, should not be too hard. (Your have a function that searches for a string in a file, and the file is determined by the language). The bad thing is that you would need to set all the strings on your user interface objects programmatically.